# Solr indexing problem

Tags: indexing, solr

I am new to Solr.
When i index the files, every variable gets indexed, but some are not searchable, how can i stop solr from displaying any results in that case.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you post an example?

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer This is a valid question- Solr does seem to hide some documents whilst showing others when searching for \*:\* I too would like to find out why.

Comment: @Fergie: Solr doesn't hide any documents, that's why I ask for examples, so I can better assess the real problem.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer If you are new to solr "rows" is a form of unexpected document hiding- see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

If you want SOLR to not search all the fields, you can be very specific in your query about what fields to search.  This is probably the best for performance too:

```
(title:grisham) OR (author:grisham) OR (publisher:grisham)
```

Alternatively, you can set "indexed=false" but "stored=true" in your schema if you never want to search or sort by those fields.  If you do want to search or sort on those fields then you will want to index them.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are not setting the "rows" parameter- try putting ...&rows=100... into your URL.

Solr defaults to max 10 results if "rows" is not set